# How do programs APIs work with plugins written in Python?

Tags: python, api

Some (often open-source) programs have special APIs for adding additional plugins written in Python, for example GIMP (gimp-fu) or Blender (bpy). How do these APIs work and how does GIMP, written in C, communicate with a plugin written in Python?

Some example, some pseudo code for Blenders bpy API:

````py
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(1, -8, 5))
```
````

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html

Comment: Jep, thats what I need, thanks!